# How to test internals of an Objective-C framework with Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, testing, module, frameworks

I have a framework/module written in Objective-C and want to test its external interfaces *and* internals in Swift. For that I created a new test target in the same project, targeting the framework. In the Swift code I can import the module and use the public classes without a problem. However, I can't access the internal classes in my tests.

I tried the following:

- I set the visibility of the internal sources to "Project". For what I understood that should make them available to code in the same project. It doesn't work, though. Or do I need to import them differently then?
- I also tried the new `@testable import` feature of Swift 2 in Xcode 7, but that doesn't seem to work (yet) for Objective-C frameworks.

What I came up with is to manually import all privat sources I want to test in the bridging header of the test target. That works. However, it doesn't feel like it's the intended way of testing an Objective-C framework with Swift.

Any ideas on how to do that better?

Comment: Frank - I have internals visible by adding import statements for their headers into the Bridging Header of the test project. Is this what you're doing?

My main issue is a little bit more esoteric than yours. I can see any internal methods as long as they don't have parameters. Have you seen anything similar?

Comment: Hmm, this is odd. Yes, I just import them in the bridging header of the test target, and no, I haven't encountered such problems yet. Are you using variadic argument lists? Because Swift can't convert those methods. Also, sometimes just the auto-completion in Xcode doesn't work, but the code still compiles. Have you tried that?

Comment: As far as I understood the bridging-headers, this is the way to go to expose private headers to swift, while public headers are exposed via the umbrella-header of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

The way I have handled such issues in the past is to make public classes within the framework that subclass your internal classes that you want to test. You can add compiler flags to make them only built with debug or test configurations.

For instance, if you had a class called `SomeClass`, you would have `SomeClassTest` that would override all the methods publicly. Doing this also gives you the handy ability to easily include test logic, such as inserting dummy data where needed etc.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue.

I worked around it by defining an Objective C extension as a test helper that only adds the definitions of the methods I want to test. Then I added the extension header to the bridging header.

For example:

```
    #import "ClassIWantToTest.h"
    @interface ClassIWantToTest (Internals)

        - (BOOL)privateMethodToTest;

    @end
```

And in the bridging header:

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//
#import "ClassIWantToTest.h"
#import "ClassIWantToTest+Internals.h"
```

Not as good as @testable, but less intrusive than subclassing and the extension can be defined in your test target so you don't need to worry about fiddling with compiler flags.